# Erro no create asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

> Não foi possível descriptografar o token antifalsificação. Se este
>   aplicativo for hospedado por um Web Farm ou cluster, garanta que todos
>   os computadores executem a mesma versão do ASP.NET Web Pages e que a
>   configuração  especifique chaves de validação e
>   criptografia explícitas. Não é possível usar AutoGenerate em um
>   cluster.

Após procurar no google solução não consegui encontrar solução, como posso resolver?

Comment: Explique melhor o seu problema

Comment: Tenho um formulario enorme, parti ele usando partial view, em varias paginas, ao tentar inserir um botao de create e submetero formulario em qualquer das paginas obtenho esse erro

Comment: E o que isso tem a ver com o create?, apresente o seu código... Mas ao que parece o seu problema é relacionado ao `Antiforgery Token`... Aonde e quando você recebe essa mensagem de erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso se deve a não teres o `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` no form ou teres em duplicado (pelas várias partial views).

Comment: Foi isso  mesmo eu removi. O AntiForgeryToken() e foi resolvido

Comment: @RaphApresentacao o recomendado é utilizar e não remover. Verifique se você tem tanto na view quando na controller. Provavelmente deu erro por que só setou para um deles...